# SQL Query I can't figure out

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tables:

```
contest_images {contestID, imageID}
image {ID, userID}
user {ID}
```

(They contain more information than that, but this is all we need)

My query so far:

```
SELECT imageID, userID FROM contest_images
JOIN image ON contest_images.imageID = image.ID 
JOIN user ON user.ID = image.userID
ORDER BY contest_images.imageID  DESC
```

The contest_images can contain multiple images from one user (which is intended)

**I want to** retrieve the x newest all users have added. (So I can restrict the users to only have one image in the contest at a time)

I also tried to make a view displaying {contestID, imageID, userID}.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you really cannot find what you're looking for in previous threads, consider posting up proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: SELECT imageID, userID FROM contest_images
JOIN image ON contest_images.imageID = image.ID 
JOIN user ON user.ID = image.userID
ORDER BY contest_images.imageID  DESC limit x;

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Do u want to select the top x results in your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT MAX(imageID), userID FROM contest_images
JOIN image ON contest_images.imageID = image.ID 
JOIN user ON user.ID = image.userID
GROUP BY image.userID
```

Comment: Yup, I used ur query only at the fiddle, just added the link to the fiddle to support your ans, and easy way to check. :)

Answer (score 2):

To limit to one image/ latest image in contest at a time you can use Top operator as :

```
SELECT top 1 imageID, userID FROM contest_images
JOIN [image] ON contest_images.imageID = [image].ID 
JOIN [user] ON [user].ID = image.userID
ORDER BY contest_images.imageID  DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys very much! :)

I went with

```
SELECT contestID, MAX(imageID), userID FROM contest_images
JOIN image ON contest_images.imageID = image.ID 
JOIN user ON user.ID = image.userID
GROUP BY image.userID
```

Hence the contestID will be specified in a WHERE clause in the end :)

But thanks alot both of you :P (I really was stuck on this.. :( )